# How to create database with doctrine2?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have setup a new dev enviorment via docker. I have a symfony2 (2.6) application, so I want to intitalize the mysql database using the `app/console doctrine` approach.

Yet when running

```
$ php app/console doctrine:database:create --if-not-exists
```

I get this error message:

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]                                                
  An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown database 'local_api'  

  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]                          
  SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown database 'local_api'

  [PDOException]                                               
  SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown database 'local_api'
```

It true that the mysql database does not exist. I want to create in the first place. What's going on here?

I found a [bug report for the doctrine/doctrine-bundle](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/384), yet we are already using the fixed version 1.5.

I also found a [symfony2.6 issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12278), yet it also prevails after upgrading symfony2 to 2.7.5.

I know that I can create them when I connect direclty to my mysql database and run `CREATE DATABASE local_api`, yet I want my workflow to go through doctrine2.

And just to make absolutly sure that the issue is unrelated to my databse setup I ran:

```
$ mysql --host=10.10.10.10 --user=foo --password=bar 
mysql> CREATE DATABASE local_api;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> Bye
$ php app/console doctrine:database:create --if-not-exists
Database `local_api` for connection named default already exists. Skipped.
```

I then can drop the database using

```
php app/console doctrine:database:drop --force
```

Yet recreating it fails again with above mentioned error.

This errror also occurs while trying to clear the cache via:

```
./app/console cache:clear
```

So it seems related to how symfony2 initalized the whole db stack.

The verbose error message looks like this:

```
[2015-10-06 17:26:28] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure".  {"uid":"c9f3fb0"}
[2015-10-06 17:26:28] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onCommand".  {"uid":"c9f3fb0"}
Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true
  Clearing outdated warmup directory
  Warming up cache



  [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]                                        
  An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown database 'local_api'  



Exception trace:
 () at ~/src/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php:103
 Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\AbstractMySQLDriver->convertException() at ~/src/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php:133
 Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException::driverException() at ~/src/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php:47
 Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver->connect() at ~/src/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:360
 Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->connect() at ~/src/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:429
 Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->getDatabasePlatformVersion() at ~/src/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:389
 Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->detectDatabasePlatform() at ~/src/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:328
 Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->getDatabasePlatform() at ~/src/api/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/ConnectionFactory.php:61
 Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\ConnectionFactory->createConnection() at ~/src/api/app/cache/de_/ap_DevDebugProjectContainer.php:1093
 ap_DevDebugProjectContainer->getDoctrine_Dbal_DefaultConnectionService() at ~/src/api/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2155
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at ~/src/api/app/cache/de_/ap_DevDebugProjectContainer.php:1142
 ap_DevDebugProjectContainer->getDoctrine_Orm_DefaultEntityManagerService() at ~/src/api/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2155
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/ManagerRegistry.php:35
 Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ManagerRegistry->getService() at ~/src/api/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/AbstractManagerRegistry.php:226
 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\AbstractManagerRegistry->getManagers() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/CacheWarmer/ProxyCacheWarmer.php:54
 Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\CacheWarmer\ProxyCacheWarmer->warmUp() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/CacheWarmer/CacheWarmerAggregate.php:48
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\CacheWarmer\CacheWarmerAggregate->warmUp() at ~/src/api/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2641
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer() at ~/src/api/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2411
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/CacheClearCommand.php:128
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheClearCommand->warmup() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/CacheClearCommand.php:90
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheClearCommand->execute() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:259
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:886
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:96
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at ~/src/api/app/console:27





  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]                  
  SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown database 'local_api'  



Exception trace:
 () at ~/src/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:47
 Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection::__construct() at ~/src/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php:45
 Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver->connect() at ~/src/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:360
 Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->connect() at ~/src/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:429
 Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->getDatabasePlatformVersion() at ~/src/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:389
 Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->detectDatabasePlatform() at ~/src/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:328
 Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->getDatabasePlatform() at ~/src/api/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/ConnectionFactory.php:61
 Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\ConnectionFactory->createConnection() at ~/src/api/app/cache/de_/ap_DevDebugProjectContainer.php:1093
 ap_DevDebugProjectContainer->getDoctrine_Dbal_DefaultConnectionService() at ~/src/api/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2155
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at ~/src/api/app/cache/de_/ap_DevDebugProjectContainer.php:1142
 ap_DevDebugProjectContainer->getDoctrine_Orm_DefaultEntityManagerService() at ~/src/api/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2155
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/ManagerRegistry.php:35
 Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ManagerRegistry->getService() at ~/src/api/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/AbstractManagerRegistry.php:226
 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\AbstractManagerRegistry->getManagers() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/CacheWarmer/ProxyCacheWarmer.php:54
 Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\CacheWarmer\ProxyCacheWarmer->warmUp() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/CacheWarmer/CacheWarmerAggregate.php:48
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\CacheWarmer\CacheWarmerAggregate->warmUp() at ~/src/api/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2641
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer() at ~/src/api/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2411
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/CacheClearCommand.php:128
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheClearCommand->warmup() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/CacheClearCommand.php:90
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheClearCommand->execute() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:259
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:886
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:96
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at ~/src/api/app/console:27





  [PDOException]                                       
  SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown database 'local_api'  



Exception trace:
 () at ~/src/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43
 PDO->__construct() at ~/src/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43
 Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection->__construct() at ~/src/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php:45
 Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver->connect() at ~/src/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:360
 Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->connect() at ~/src/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:429
 Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->getDatabasePlatformVersion() at ~/src/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:389
 Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->detectDatabasePlatform() at ~/src/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:328
 Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->getDatabasePlatform() at ~/src/api/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/ConnectionFactory.php:61
 Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\ConnectionFactory->createConnection() at ~/src/api/app/cache/de_/ap_DevDebugProjectContainer.php:1093
 ap_DevDebugProjectContainer->getDoctrine_Dbal_DefaultConnectionService() at ~/src/api/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2155
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at ~/src/api/app/cache/de_/ap_DevDebugProjectContainer.php:1142
 ap_DevDebugProjectContainer->getDoctrine_Orm_DefaultEntityManagerService() at ~/src/api/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2155
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/ManagerRegistry.php:35
 Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ManagerRegistry->getService() at ~/src/api/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/AbstractManagerRegistry.php:226
 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\AbstractManagerRegistry->getManagers() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/CacheWarmer/ProxyCacheWarmer.php:54
 Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\CacheWarmer\ProxyCacheWarmer->warmUp() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/CacheWarmer/CacheWarmerAggregate.php:48
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\CacheWarmer\CacheWarmerAggregate->warmUp() at ~/src/api/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2641
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer() at ~/src/api/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2411
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/CacheClearCommand.php:128
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheClearCommand->warmup() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/CacheClearCommand.php:90
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheClearCommand->execute() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:259
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:886
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:96
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at ~/src/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at ~/src/api/app/console:27


cache:clear [--no-warmup] [--no-optional-warmers]
```

Comment: It seems to be [an issue in symfony2.6](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12278), I'll need to check

Comment: Just updated to symfony2.7.5, issue still persisting.

Comment: Just tested and it works as expected: 1st run:
`Created database "project" for connection named default`

2nd run:
`Database "project" for connection named default already exists. Skipped.`

Comment: Does your user have sufficient privileges for creating databases?

Comment: @lxg When I create the database on mysql directly I use the same credentials as the symfony2 app would use, so yes.

Comment: Are you sure that you're using the same credentials when running from command line as you would from a web page?

Comment: @Simba: The configuration is usually the same for web and console, as Symfony uses its `parameters.yml` file

Comment: @Simba Yes, as I can drop the database via `php app/console doctrine:database:drop` and create the schema once I created it manually. It fails if the database does not exist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you still want to do it with the latest version of `doctrine/dbal`, all you have to do is to specify the `server_version` in the dbal configuration:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                dbname:         local_api
                user:           root
                password:       null
                host:           localhost
                driver:         pdo_mysql
                server_version: '5.5' # your database server version here
```

I can't tell you why they didn't put a default server_version though, but here is the discussion about it https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/351

Since you're using a mysql database, here is how to see your server_version:

```
mysql --version

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.44, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3
```

We see that the current Distrib is `5.5`.

Of course I recommend you to set this value in `parameters.yml`.

Comment: `server_version` solved my apps issue as well. Thanks for posting.

Comment: Hi, this solved my issue. But can you please explain why did this worked? I never had to use this before. What have changed? Why I need to supply my mysql database version, this does not make any sense? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It turned out to be a regression in the `doctrine/dbal` component.

I required `"doctrine/dbal":"2.4.*` in the `composer.json`.

Then it worked fine:

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)                                                
  - Removing doctrine/dbal (v2.5.2)
  - Installing doctrine/dbal (v2.4.4)
    Downloading: 100% 

$ php app/console doctrine:database:create
Created database for connection named `local_api`
```

[The issue is known](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/461) and as of yet waiting for resoultion.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't know why generating the DB fails for you. However, you can as well create the database manually and grant permissions to the desired user on the command line, then have Doctrine fill the database:

First, create the database and grant permissions:

```
CREATE DATABASE whatever;
GRANT ALL ON whatever.* TO user@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'pAsSwOrD';
```

Then, let Doctrine set up the database:

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update --force --complete
```

Or, alternatively, let Doctrine dump the SQL commands it would execute:

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql --complete
```

Comment: I pointed out in the question that I can create a database using the mysql client fine. I consider this a workaround to the problem, yet not a solution.