# Symfony 2.7 application without created database

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am experiencing some very odd behavior with my Symfony2 application using Doctrine with PDO_mysql:

After cloning it from repository, I need to install it via composer, without the database being already created. I want to create the database later with `app/console doctrine:database:create` command, with parameters specified in *parameters.yml* during installation.

But when I run `composer install`, I get this error on composer **post-install-cmd** *"Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache"*:

```
[PDOException] SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown database 'test'
```

First I thought this is a duplicate of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32965837/how-to-create-database-with-doctrine2). But specifying `server_version` in doctrine connection config in *app/config/config.yml* doesn't help. Also, other solutions I have found advised to revert to earlier version of `doctrine/dbal`, like 2.4.4 or 2.4.3. I tried any combination of `doctrine/dbal`, `doctrine/orm` and `doctrine/doctrine-bundle` versions, but the behavior didn't change.

After that, I noticed that running commands that throw this error repeatedly work. E.g. when I run `app/console doctrine:database:create` on a freshly installed copy (I temporarily deleted those post-install scripts, that were throwing said error) first time, it throws this error. When I run it immediately again, it creates it succesfully:

```
Created database `test` for connection named default
```

It happens also with completely unrelated console commands. When I run `app/console` to show me available commands for the first time, I get *unknown database 'test'*. When I run it immediately again, everything is OK and after that it even lets me create the database with `database:create` command.

To me this looks like something needs to be initialized after installation first, in order for the **pdo_mysql connection** to work properly. But what is it? I am using *composer.json* setup similar to the [Symfony Standard Edition](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.7/composer.json). But no matter what I try, the result is the same... After 2 days, I am really desperate now.

*Note 1: If I create the database manually before specifying it's name in parameters.yml, everything works as expected. But this is not an option for me. I need to be able to run `composer install` with all **post-install-cmds** before I create the DB.*

*Note 2: I am trying all this on localhost Linux machine with manually installed MySQL AND at the same time on Windows machine with xampp stack using MariaDB. The behavior is the same on both...*

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34024275/2270041

Comment: Matteo: Thank you, but specifying server_version in DBAL config doesn't help. Still the same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I called some of the problematic commands with verbose and I came up with an exception trace, containing this:

```
Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\AbstractSchemaManager->tablesExist() 
    at vendor/lexik/translation-bundle/Lexik/Bundle/TranslationBundle/Storage/DoctrineORMStorage.php:28

Lexik\Bundle\TranslationBundle\Storage\DoctrineORMStorage->translationsTablesExist() 
    at vendor/lexik/translation-bundle/Lexik/Bundle/TranslationBundle/EventDispatcher/GetDatabaseResourcesListener.php:41
```

So I checked *LexikTranslationBundle* and found [this issue](https://github.com/lexik/LexikTranslationBundle/issues/142), fixed by [this commit](https://github.com/lexik/LexikTranslationBundle/commit/014810f0f1d190760456b0861bad90974c4f2910). Unfortunately for me, the fix is only merged into version 4, which requires *Symfony 2.8*. I proposed merging into other versions too, but in a meantime I ended up forking the bundle and fixing it for myself. Now everything works as expected.